# Caps lock problem

Tags: capslock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CAPS LOCK bug makes turning it off too slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58080/caps-lock-bug-makes-turning-it-off-too-slow)

I'm not a shifter. When I use upper-case characters I use the caps lock. However on Ubuntu when I turn caps off, then hit the next character; It's still active. It's like I hit the next character faster than Ubuntu can turn caps off.

`EXample TExt WHen I TYpe FAst (NOrmal)`

Its very irritating, especially whilst programming...

Keyboard: Razer Lycosa Mirror

I'd appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've often seen this behavior on USB keyboards when using the shift key (because the keyboard can't keep up with the user's typing rate) but that seems different from your case here.

Comment: I wish the other post had more info....